# Understanding Unix/Linux Mounting

Tags: unix

I'm trying to understand mount points and mounting a little better. I understand that in order to access a file system it has to be mounted. If I create a local directory in my home directory and put text files in it, is this considered to be a file system? Why don't I have to mount it to access it? What if other users on the network want access it, do they have to mount it?

Comment: It's off topic here (IMO).

Comment: I added an answer, to be nice.  But this is really off topic.

Comment: You have one master filesystem, mounted as `/`. Subdirectores are *not* another filesystems. Now, when you want to access another filesystem (say, you plugged in pendrive, and want to access data in it), you mount its partition as a directory, and from that point, that directory represents another filesystem.

Comment: yeah sorry, i just realized there is a separate website for Unix/Linux questions, I'll use that in the future

Answer (score 2):

Mounting is really more for volumes like actual physical devices.  Thumbdrives, CDs, Hard drives, etc...  But you can also mount a file as a file system, like an ISO (disk image) file.

In terms of what to do with your folders, yes, you can share them on the network, and make them mountable volumes.  But that's not really what it's for.
If anything, the remote system would be the one mounting the folder as a network drive.  Locally, though, it's just a folder.

Answer (score 0):

To mount something in the file system it's more for external volumes, disks, network file systems, etc.
If you create a folder in your home directory you don't have to mount it because it's already mounted.

Every file and folder you have in your hard drive is meant to be in the file system. The file system is how your folder, files and permissions are put together.